# Get Woocommerce product attribute/variation in IONIC

Tags: wordpress, api, ionic-framework, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need a little help.
I'm trying to get the attributes and variations of a product. Here is all I'm doing this:

product.html

```
<div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-body" ng-repeat="attribute in product.attributes">
                <h2>{{attribute.name}}</h2>

                <ion-radio ng-repeat="variation in product.variations">
                  {{variation.price}}
                  <div ng-repeat="vaAttribute in variation.attributes">                    
                  {{vaAttribute.option}}
                  </div>
                    </ion-radio>
              </div>
        </div>
```

controller.js

```
     .controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, WC, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $localStorage, $rootScope){

      var Woocommerce = WC.WC();

      Woocommerce.get('products/' + $stateParams.productID, function(err, data, res){
        if(err)
          console.log(err);

        $scope.product = JSON.parse(res).product;
        $scope.images = JSON.parse(res).product.images;

........................................................
........................................................
```

If I have one attribute with variations it works fine.
But if I have more than one attribute it will print all variations from all attributes in the loop.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPxF5.png)